# Error installing RVM in gitbash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rvm

The command that I tried to install **RVM** in gitbash is

> `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

The error that I am getting is:

**bash: line 84: conditional binary operator expected url: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 6628)**

Comment: Please supply additional info about your env. Proxy? Does `curl -sSL http://wikipedia.org` successfully dowload page? Then run curl w/out `-s` (silent) option and post an output here.

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: yes i am using windows to install RVM

Comment: it looks like you could not write a file to disk, you can add `--debug` flag to the command to see more details, if that does not help add `--trace` (warning - it will be big)

Comment: I don't believe RVM works on Windows yet without Cygwin.